# How to make a private function into a helper function?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have been writing tests for my app. However when running my tests I keep getting the error `Stall on main thread` on my function

```
private func waitForElementToAppear(testCase: XCTestCase,
                                    element: XCUIElement,
                                    file: String = #file,
                                    line: UInt = #line) {

    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    testCase.expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate,
                                     evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)

    testCase.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 5 seconds."
            testCase.recordFailureWithDescription(message,
                                                  inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I use this function several times in my tests/code. How can I convert this into a helper function so I only have to have this function written once. Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more swifty to use an extension:

```
extension XCTestCase {

    // your function here
}
```

So you can use it in all your test classes without an additional class

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have moved the function into the extension class - however now I am getting the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'waitForElement' ` when trying to use the function e.g.  `waitForElementToAppear(app.staticTexts["Add a comment"])`

Comment: remove the `private`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper class and make the function static

```
class Helper {
    static func waitForElementToAppear(testCase: XCTestCase,
                                element: XCUIElement,
                                file: String = #file,
                                line: UInt = #line) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That way wherever you need to use the function you can call the function on helper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I believe the using the extension method is my preferred way of use :)